# Object.toString() does not return the hashcode value of the object in java but instead give some string

Tags: java

I have written the following code:-

```
Test ob = new Test();
System.out.println(ob.toString());
System.out.println(ob.hashCode());
```

and the output is

```
Test@15db9742
366712642
```

i understand that the second value is the hashcode of the object and it is an integer value but i am not able to understand what is the first value. If it is the hashcode of the object then how can it be string and not integer

Comment: Who told you toString() returns hash code, or it is hash code. By the name and syntax, it returns/should return when overridden a string describing the object.

Comment: what exactly do you think toString is supposed to do? if you want the hashcode, call hashCode

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It represents classname@HashCode_in_Hexadeciaml_form. So, the string which you are seeing is actually the hexadecimal form of the integer hashcode

Answer (score 13):

If you read the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString()) for `toString` very carefully:

> The toString method for class Object returns a string consisting of the name of the class of which the object is an instance, the at-sign character `@', and the unsigned ***hexadecimal*** representation of the hash code of the object. In other words, this method returns a string equal to the value of:
>
> `getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())`

366712642 in hex is exactly 15DB9742!

> If it is the hashcode of the object then how can it be string and not integer?

As you can see from the docs, it is the class name, plus `@`, plus the dashcode, not just the hash code. Also, the method's name is `toString`. It would be weird if it returned an `int`, wouldn't it?

Answer (score 2):

You can look the source code of `Object.java`. `toString`  method is meant to provide information about class at runtime, so can be overriden. What you're doing is calling the default `toString` method from Object.java. It simply returns following:

```
getClass().getName() + "@" + Integer.toHexString(hashCode()
```

Hence the output.

See code [here](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/jdk/file/tip/src/share/classes/java/lang/Object.java)